# How to add mobile phone number to people search results?

Tags: 2013, display-template, people-search

I'm trying to add some more information to the `peopleresults.aspx`.

I tried to follow the instructions [here](http://wwolfe.blogspot.de/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-add-user-profile.html) but I get an `undefined error` for the `has_mPhone` variable.

Is there something wrong is that blog post and how can I add the mobile phone number?

Answer (score 3):

I do it for Twitter Name in a sample.

1. Create the Managed Property if necessary
2. Full People Crawl
3. Copy the Item_Person.html file
4. Add your property and the code to render it
5. Publish the Display Template
6. Create the Result Type rule
7. Test

The whole walk through it here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Video Here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2014/03/08/spc322-sharepoint-search-display-templates-and-query-rules/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [example](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-show-the-fax-number-in-people-search-results-in-sharepoint-2010/) out. The example is around adding `fax`, but you can do the same thing around adding phone numbers.

Comment: Your example is for SP 2010 so it's a little different to 2013 and I couldn't find out how to change the template in SP 2013.

Comment: try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx around customizing display template